# when i press back button getiing this ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined and related to react-native-modal package

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-modal

location of file as mention below
*C:\Uuuuuu\node_modules\react-native-modal\dist\modal.js*

here is the piece of code related to issue

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackButtonPress);
    DeviceEventEmitter.removeListener.remove('didUpdateDimensions', this.handleDimensionsUpdate);
    if (this.interactionHandle) {
        InteractionManager.clearInteractionHandle(this.interactionHandle);
        this.interactionHandle = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution about this?